# Creating custom native arch linux netbook from android tablet?

Tags: linux, command-line, arch-linux, bootloader, arm

A while ago I have decided to make a netbook out of an android tablet I had lying around, by 3D printing a case for it and using an 87 key mechanical keyboard as the embedded keyboard. I mainly plan to use it without an xserver, so no mouse required. Since the tablet does not consume much power, I'll just throw in a ton of batteries as well, so I'll be able to use this thing all day long without charging.

I plan to put the arm version of a linux distro on it(arch). I know that there are ways to emulate linux on android, but the tablet only features an MT8127 SOC (it's an Insignia Flex 10.1). There is no arch port for this chip at the moment, and I would like to give a shot at porting it. I also know that the android bootloader is locked and so I will need to reflash the emmc chip with the new OS as well as the new bootloader.

My questions are:

Am I going to have to write my own bootloader for the chip, or are there any open source ones which could be used as templates?

Are there any good guides or sources on how to port arch? I know that there is a [guide on how to build the linux kernel for an MT8127](https://github.com/PixNDom/android_kernel_mediatek). I have also heard of the Yocto project for designing linux distros for embedded systems, but that seems like too much work, since I would manually have to do updates myself, which without a package manager would be tedious.

Also, what does the default screen orientation depend on? If I remember correctly, screen rotation requires emulation. Does that mean that the driver IC for the tablet has a predefined screen orientation built in, or is 
it defined by the bootloader?

All help is appreciatedd! Thank you.